# Creating a countdown timer with Redux

Tags: javascript, redux, redux-thunk

I want to create a timer that will indicate a flash message (“Saved!”) to be shown for a given duration value, e.g. 30 seconds.

My thinking how to accomplish this with Redux goes like this:

1. The countdown is fired.
2. Every second, the `TIMER_TICK` action type is sent to the reducer.
3. When the duration value (in seconds) is reached, the `timer` should be cleared.

```js
const initialState = {
  count: 0,
  timerOn: false,
}

const tick = () => ({ type: TIMER_TICK });

let timer = null;

export const startFlashMessageTimer = () => dispatch => {
  clearInterval(timer);
  timer = setInterval(() => dispatch(tick()), 1000);
}
```

But I’m stuck at where to put the logic that checks if the count value is reached (30 in this case). Any suggestion how/where I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
export const startFlashMessageTimer = () => (dispatch, getState) => {
  let timer = null;
  clearInterval(timer);
  timer = setInterval(() => {
      dispatch(tick());
      const { count } = getState();
      if (count >= 5) { clearInterval(timer) }
  }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: I think it would be preferable to have the timer's status stored in application state. updated the question with `initialState` to show this.

Comment: @FellowStranger How about now?

Comment: Hm, unfortunately `count` doesn't get updated in the `setInterval` function - hence, the `count` check never passes.. I've tried to call `getState()` inside the function but getState doesn't seem to get latest state either..

Comment: Are you updating `count` in the reducer?

Comment: Spot on! My mistake :D